# Perl adding value instead of characters

Tags: perl, variables, printing, nmap

Im running a perl script to scan several hosts. When i put a single host in

```
$scanner->scan('-sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms 111.111.111.111');
```

it runs fine, but when I try to add a variable value inside by parsing a file with list of hosts

```
$scanner->scan('-sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms $host');
```

The program just assumes $host as characters, is there anyway to get around this? I'm using nmap::scanner as my module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing quotes by double-quotes:

```
$scanner->scan("-sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms $host");
```

or place `$host`  outside:

```
$scanner->scan('-sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms '.$host);
```

Comment: Thanks, how does "." before $host makes a difference? Before posting here, I had tried   $scanner->scan('-sS -p 1-1024 -sV -O --max-rtt-timeout 200ms ' $host); (without the "." and I had an error, but yea it works now.

Comment: @LeRay `.` is the string concatenation operator. You should really take some time to learn the Perl language. String interpolation and concatenation are pretty basic. Here's an [excellent book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) to get started (both print and free online versions available).

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong type of quotes

```
'
```

does not interpolate variables so

```
$x='fish';

$b='deep fried $x';
```

sets $b to `deep fried $x`

whereas

$b="deep fried $x";

sets $b to `deep fried fish`

See perldoc perlop for more details